# How does ImageMagick perform under high load?

Tags: php, canvas, imagemagick, image-manipulation

A small part of the app I am working on includes photo filters.  I am currently in the research/mock up phase and have found the following options that seem to work well.

1. Server side processing with images sent via ajax and replaced in the DOM, using a combination of GD and ImageMagick to perform the processing.
2. Client side processing using html5 canvas and javascript.

I have mockups of both and will likely use a combination of the two depending on browser support.

However I would like to know how suitable ImageMagick is as the app scales up.  Am I likely to run into performance issues as the userbase grows? Is there anything I should be aware of if I were to go with this implementation?

And finally, are there any other high performance alternatives?  What would be the fastest way of performing browser based image filtering (we are talking sepia/greyscale/oil painting style filters)

I realise this is quite a broad question but hopefully someone has some experience or comments on the issue.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: What was your final solution? I have a question running re. IM and GPU utilisation. I want to know if IM can only use GPU on OSX.